# How do I check to see that the login password given is correct with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, authentication

I've tried this `.authenticate` method everyone was talking about but you need to write a `self.authenticate` implementation in the model in order to use it in the controller and it requires BCrypt. That's fine, but the only methods for BCrypt that compare passwords both require a salt as well, and the salt isn't stored in my database. I don't even know how to store it there if I wanted to, but someone here at SO once said that there's no reason to store salts in the database anyway so I would rather avoid it.

How to I compare the password provided to the password in the database for a given user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to implement a `authenticate` method by yourself. You just have to include `has_secure_password` in your model.

**Example:**

Gemfile:

```
gem 'bcrypt'    # Is needed for `has_secure_password` to hash the password!
```

Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
end
```

Migration:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest    # Be sure to have this in your migration or otherwise the `has_secure_password` won't work!
    end

    add_index :users, :email, unique: true   # Good practice to ensure unique email addresses.
  end
end
```

This takes care automatically for the stuff like hashing of the password and adds methods like `#authenticate`.

Authentication:

```
User.find_by(email: params[:user][:email]).authenticate(params[:user][:password])    # This returns the user record if the password is valid or `false` if not

# ----

# Example

class SessionsController < ApplicationController
   # ...

   def create    # Responsible for creating a session
     @user = User.find_by(email: params[:user][:email])

     if @user.present? && @user.authenticate(params[:user][:password])
       # Do login stuff since the password is valid
     else
       # Don't let the user in.
     end
   end
end
```

The `#authenticate` method takes care of all the hashing and so on.

**I don't recommend you to store plain passwords. This would be a big security problem since hackers would have all passwords of your users if your database is compromised.**

- Also take a look into the [Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html). It explains it in more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the basics. I've made it past all of this, but I need to know how to check whether a given password matches the one hashed in the database.

Comment: You are great! Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't compare passwords, you compare a store hash of a given password with the incoming password (hashed as well) - ideally with a secure mechanism.

In any case, I highly recommend an existing solution (such as  [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)) and warn you about implementing it on your own.

Comment: I understand that but how exactly do I compare the two hashes?

Answer (score 0):

(very old question, this is mostly a reminder for myself now)

If you're using [Devise](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise) you can query [valid_password?](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise%2FModels%2FDatabaseAuthenticatable:valid_password%3F)

```
user.valid_password?('wrong password 1') # false
user.valid_password?('valid password 1') # true
```